# Espresso doubleClick() does not work on some devices

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-instrumentation

I'm writing UI tests using Espresso. I need to test a flow on double click but failed to do so on some devices.

```kotlin
onView(withId(R.id.idOfView))
            .check(matches(someAssertion()))
            .perform(doubleClick())
```

But this performs single click, (*sometimes two single clicks*) on my *Nexus 5 - API Level 23* emulator. Funny workaround

```
perform(click(), doubleClick())
```

it works. But I'm not sure if I can trust this. Is there anything that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

For two clicks to be recognized as a double-click, the second click's DOWN event must occur within `[min, max]` ms of the first click's UP event. `min` and `max` may vary across different devices, but values I've seen are [40 ms min, and 300 ms max](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/view/ViewConfiguration.java#120).

A [`doubleClick`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/testing/+/android-support-test/espresso/core/src/main/java/android/support/test/espresso/action/ViewActions.java#292) `ViewAction` leads to a [`GeneralClickAction`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/testing/+/android-support-test/espresso/core/src/main/java/android/support/test/espresso/action/GeneralClickAction.java#34) with a [`DOUBLE` `Tapper`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/testing/+/android-support-test/espresso/core/src/main/java/android/support/test/espresso/action/Tap.java#76).

That `DOUBLE` `Tapper` will wait for the minimum required delay before performing its second tap.
What may be happening on your emulator is that it's not running fast enough for the second click event to be injected before you've passed the maximum allowed delay.

When you do `perform(click(), doubleClick())` there might not be any added wait between the `click` and the `doubleClick`, so the `click` and the first click of the `doubleClick` may end up being recognized as a double-click on your slow emulator. That doesn't guarantee that it would work on an actual device, or on an emulator running on a faster computer.